# Incrementar um contador dentro de um foreach em php

Tags: php, loop, foreach

Num laço *foreach* preciso incrementar um contador para definir o *tabindex* dos campos do formulário, para que o resultado seja:

```
<input type="text" name="endereco[0][cep]" value="00000-000" tabindex="1">
<input type="text" name="endereco[0][rua]" value="Rua XXXX" tabindex="2">
<input type="text" name="endereco[1][cep]" value="11111-111" tabindex="3">
<input type="text" name="endereco[1][rua]" value="Rua YYYY" tabindex="4">
```

O que eu tenho:

```
<?php
$i = 0;

foreach ($enderecos as $endereco) {
?>
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $i?>][cep]" value="<?php echo $endereco['cep']; ?>" tabindex="">
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $i?>][rua]" value="<?php echo $endereco['rua']; ?>" tabindex="">
<?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: Eu não sei como posso incrementar um contador para definir o tabindex

Comment: Me parece caso de usar um for, e não foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta trabalhar com mais uma variável para `tabindex` que incrementa 2 a cada iteração do foreach

[**veja funcionando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/NIhN73)

```
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
  $enderecos = array(array('cep' => '00000-00', 'rua' => 'Rua XXXX'), array('cep' => '11111-111', 'rua' => 'Rua YYYY'));

foreach ($enderecos as $endereco) {
?>
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $i?>][cep]" value="<?php echo $endereco['cep']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo ($j+1) ?>">
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $i?>][rua]" value="<?php echo $endereco['rua']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo ($j+2) ?>">
<?php
    $i++;
    $j+=2;
}
```

[**veja outro exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/7Uyszp)

[**outro exemplo no ideone**](https://ideone.com/Pu08Mh)

Answer (score 4):

[Segundo a documentação oficial do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php), a cada iteração, o valor do elemento atual é atribuído a $value e o ponteiro interno do array avança uma posição (então, na próxima iteração, se estará olhando para o próximo elemento).

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
    statement
```

**Editado**

Então, seu trecho de código ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
<?php

  $enderecos = array(array('cep' => '00000-00', 'rua' => 'Rua XXXX'), array('cep' => '11111-111', 'rua' => 'Rua YYYY'));

  $i = 1;

  foreach($enderecos as $indice=>$endereco) {

    foreach($endereco as $key=>$value) {
?>
      <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $indice;?>][<?php echo $key?>]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $i;?>" />
<?php
      $i++;

    }

  }

?>
```

Comment: Nesse formato vai me retornar apenas 0 e1 em ambos atributos tabindex dos inputs, mas como são 2 inputs no laço foreach preciso de uma forma que me incremente e me retorne no atributo tabindex 1, 2, 3 e 4 conforme exemplo.

Comment: Tem como, por gentileza, você postar o seu array?

Comment: $enderecos = array(array('cep' => '00000-00', 'rua' => 'Rua XXXX'), array('cep' => '11111-111', 'rua' => 'Rua YYYY'))

Comment: Acima, realizei as alterações necessárias para obter o resultado esperado.

Answer (score 0):

Para reproduzir o que imagina, basta você adicionar mais um increment ao foreach().

```
<?php
$i = 0;
$j = 0;
$tab = 1;
foreach ($enderecos as $endereco) {
?>
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $i?>][cep]" value="<?php echo $endereco['cep']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $tab; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $j?>][rua]" value="<?php echo $endereco['rua']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $tab; ?>">
<?php
    $i++;
    $j++;
    $tab++;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$i = 1;
$c = 0;
foreach ($enderecos as $endereco) {
    $j = $i + 1;
?>
<input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $c;?>][cep]" value="<?php echo $endereco['cep']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $i; ?>">
<input type="text" name="endereco[<?php echo $c;?>][rua]" value="<?php echo $endereco['rua']; ?>" tabindex="<?php echo $j; ?>">
<?php
    $i+=2; // incrementar 2
    $c++;
}
?>
```

Comment: deveria ser $c = 0; veja no ideone https://ideone.com/YaqVsD

Comment: Correcto, corrigi